# Using [sic] to correct "etc" without a period

Tags: punctuation, etc, sic

I am quoting a passage that uses the abbreviation `etc.` ... except that the `etc` has no period after it.

I read [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110589/sic-to-indicate-punctuation-errors) that you can use [*sic*] to indicate a punctuation error, but should I bother using it to indicate a *lack* of punctuation that *should* be there?

Comment: IMO, not at all worth it.

Comment: In particular, a reader might be more likely to think you're drawing attention to an allegedly incorrect choice or spelling of *etc* and would therefore be confused. Also, while the period is strictly correct, modern usage increasingly dispenses with periods used for ellipsis where the meaning is clear, hence USA (not U.S.A.), eg (not e.g.), etc. See [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-%22Etc.%22-Correctly) for a good guide on the use of *etc*. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a period/full point or full stop after "etc", when it is not at the end of a sentence, is a convention of style, not a rule.

From the (UK) Guardian style guide:

> etc
>   no full point

[The Guardian Style Guide](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-e)

Many sources of guidance advise care when using *sic*, especially when the supposed "error" in the quoted material may be merely use of an unfamiliar style convention or rule (e.g. British/American spelling or punctuation differences).

[Using *sic* correctly](https://grammarist.com/usage/sic/)